# canvas2d: cancelAnimationFrame is not working

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

### Problem

Once each item of the honeycomb moved to its end position (animation **starts by clicking** on the hexagon), it fires `stop()`. This works so far. The problem is that `stop()` is called in an infinite loop (see console logging `stop`) and it doesn't seem to me like `cancelAnimationFrame` worked.

### Goal

Once each item of the honeycomb moved to its end position, the animation should stop because there is nothing moving anymore anyway. Once you click again, each item collapses into the middle again (exactly the opposite of the opening animation), kinda like a toggle.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const hexagonArray = [];

var raf;

const items = [
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
];

class Hexagon {
  constructor(heading, subheading, idx) {
    this.idx = idx;
    this.sixtyDeg = Math.PI * 2 / 6;
    this.radius = 80;
    this.gap = 1.9;
    this.fromX = canvas.width / 2;
    this.fromY = canvas.height / 2;
    this.toX = this.fromX + this.gap * this.radius * Math.sin(this.sixtyDeg * idx);
    this.toY = this.fromY + this.gap * this.radius * Math.cos(this.sixtyDeg * idx);
    this.x = this.fromX;
    this.y = this.fromY;
    this.frames = 100;
    this.frame = 0;
    this.speedX = this.toX / this.frames;
    this.speedY = this.toY / this.frames;
    this.isCurrent = false;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.subheading = subheading;
  }

  draw() {
    const { sixtyDeg, radius, x, y, idx } = this;
    // ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    // ctx.fillText(`no.${idx}`, x, y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(
        x + radius * Math.cos(sixtyDeg * i),
        y + radius * Math.sin(sixtyDeg * i)
      );
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }

  update(shouldOpen) {
    this.x = expEaseInOut(
      this.frame,
      this.fromX,
      this.toX - this.fromX,
      this.frames  
    );

    this.y = expEaseInOut(
      this.frame,
      this.fromY,
      this.toY - this.fromY,
      this.frames  
    );

    if (
      (shouldOpen ? this.frame < this.frames : this.frame > this.frames)
      && this.idx !== 0
    ) {
      this.frame = shouldOpen
        ? this.frame + 1  // open
        : this.frame - 1; // close
    } else if (this.idx !== 0) {
      stop();
    }

    this.draw();
  }

  toggle() {
    let toggle = false;
    this.update(!toggle);
    toggle = !toggle;
  }
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.toggle();
  });
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function stop() {
  console.log('stop');
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = event;

  hexagonArray.some((hexagon) => {
    const isInRange = (
      inRange(clientX, hexagon.x - hexagon.radius, hexagon.x + hexagon.radius)
      && inRange(clientY, hexagon.y - hexagon.radius, hexagon.y + hexagon.radius)
    );
    if (isInRange) {
      raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      return true;
    }
  });
});

function init() {
  items.forEach(({ heading, subheading }, idx) => {
    hexagonArray.push(new Hexagon(heading, subheading, idx));
  });
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.draw();
  });
}

init();

/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  init();
});

function expEaseInOut(frame, initPos, distance, frames) {
  frame /= frames / 2;
  if (frame < 1) return distance/2 * Math.pow( 2, 10 * (frame - 1) ) + initPos;
  frame--;
  return distance/2 * ( -Math.pow( 2, -10 * frame) + 2 ) + initPos;
};

function inRange(n, min, max) {
  return ((n-min)*(n-max) <= 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script async src="index.js"></script>
  <title>canvas2d</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    body {
      min-width: 100vw;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    canvas {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
  <canvas
    width="440"
    height="440"
  ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your variable `raf` is used to store two different ids, but it can obviously only point to one of these. You won't be able to clear the first one. But you may prefer store a global boolean flag instead, and check in your loops if that flag is on before calling again rAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the issue is that you call the requestAnimationFrame again right after hence it keeps on looping.

```
function animate() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // You're updating the 6 hexagons & calling "cancelAnimationFrame" in here
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.toggle();
  });

  // BUT... you call the animation again just after, so it keeps looping
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

If you call your animation before updating your logic & drawing, it won't loop

```
function animate() {
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.toggle();
  });
}
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const hexagonArray = [];

let raf;

const items = [
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
  {
    heading: "Lorem Ipsum",
    subheading: "dolor sit amet",
  },
];

class Hexagon {
  constructor(heading, subheading, idx) {
    this.idx = idx;
    this.sixtyDeg = Math.PI * 2 / 6;
    this.radius = 80;
    this.gap = 1.9;
    this.fromX = canvas.width / 2;
    this.fromY = canvas.height / 2;
    this.toX = this.fromX + this.gap * this.radius * Math.sin(this.sixtyDeg * idx);
    this.toY = this.fromY + this.gap * this.radius * Math.cos(this.sixtyDeg * idx);
    this.x = this.fromX;
    this.y = this.fromY;
    this.frames = 100;
    this.frame = 0;
    this.speedX = this.toX / this.frames;
    this.speedY = this.toY / this.frames;
    this.isCurrent = false;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.subheading = subheading;
  }

  draw() {
    const { sixtyDeg, radius, x, y, idx } = this;
    // ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    // ctx.fillText(`no.${idx}`, x, y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(
        x + radius * Math.cos(sixtyDeg * i),
        y + radius * Math.sin(sixtyDeg * i)
      );
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }

  update(shouldOpen) {
    this.x = expEaseInOut(
      this.frame,
      this.fromX,
      this.toX - this.fromX,
      this.frames  
    );

    this.y = expEaseInOut(
      this.frame,
      this.fromY,
      this.toY - this.fromY,
      this.frames  
    );

    if (
      (shouldOpen ? this.frame < this.frames : this.frame > this.frames)
      && this.idx !== 0
    ) {
      this.frame = shouldOpen
        ? this.frame + 1  // open
        : this.frame - 1; // close
    } else if (this.idx !== 0) {
      stop();
    }

    this.draw();
  }

  toggle() {
    let toggle = false;
    this.update(!toggle);
    toggle = !toggle;
  }
}

function animate() {
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.toggle();
  });
}

function stop() {
  console.log('stop');
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = event;

  hexagonArray.some((hexagon) => {
    const isInRange = (
      inRange(clientX, hexagon.x - hexagon.radius, hexagon.x + hexagon.radius)
      && inRange(clientY, hexagon.y - hexagon.radius, hexagon.y + hexagon.radius)
    );
    if (isInRange) {
      raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      return true;
    }
  });
});

function init() {
  items.forEach(({ heading, subheading }, idx) => {
    hexagonArray.push(new Hexagon(heading, subheading, idx));
  });
  hexagonArray.forEach((hexagon) => {
    hexagon.draw();
  });
}

init();

/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  init();
});

function expEaseInOut(frame, initPos, distance, frames) {
  frame /= frames / 2;
  if (frame < 1) return distance/2 * Math.pow( 2, 10 * (frame - 1) ) + initPos;
  frame--;
  return distance/2 * ( -Math.pow( 2, -10 * frame) + 2 ) + initPos;
};

function inRange(n, min, max) {
  return ((n-min)*(n-max) <= 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

canvas {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="440" height="440"></canvas>
```